# How can I change some of the cards to next line, that are inside an wrapper when screen limit is reached?

Tags: css, vue.js

i want to display several elements in cards , coming from my routing system, in a similar way that i am creating my sidebar (that is working properly). i got all titles and icons, and the linking is working perfectly .

This is what i am doing: Since some of my elements, i am getting from my routing system have children (for example, i have spots for "agenda" , "sessao"  and "packs e modulos", and the last element, has two elements inside of it "packs" and "modulos") when i am checking my route file, for elements, it wraps each parent, making a wrapper for «agenda», other wrapper for «sessao», and a wrapper with the two children inside it: "packs" e " modulos" (i don't want it's parent to display.

Everything is working as i want except one thing, that is what i am struggling.  I display all my cards (wrapped)  horizontally, and when a wrapper doensn't fit on the screen it goes to the next line. With the wrappers with only one element works perfectly, however with the wrappers with children, is where i am struggling,  since if the wrapper doensn't fit the screen, the entire wrapper changes it's line, and i only want that the child that doesn't fit the line, changes to the  next line
For example, if only Agenda, Sessao and Pack fits one line, i want that only Modulo changes to the next line, instead, both Pack and Modulo are chaning.

Here is my code

```
<template>
   <div v-if="!item.hidden&&item.children" class="menu-wrapper">

    <template v-if="!item.hidden&&item.children && hasOneShowingChild(item.children,item) && (!onlyOneChild.children||onlyOneChild.noShowingChildren) && !item.alwaysShow">
      <app-link :to="resolvePath(onlyOneChild.path)">
        <!-- single -->
        
        <el-card   :index="resolvePath(onlyOneChild.path)" :class="{'submenu-title-noDropdown':!isNest} ">
          <!-- <item v-if="onlyOneChild.meta" :title="onlyOneChild.meta.title" /> -->          
          <!-- <item v-if="onlyOneChild.meta" :icon="onlyOneChild.meta.icon||item.meta.icon" :title="onlyOneChild.meta.title" :collapse="collapse" /> -->
          <!-- <span>{{ onlyOneChild.meta.title }}</span> -->
          <div class="contentCard">
            <div class="icon">
          <i :class="onlyOneChild.meta.icon" />
        </div>
          <span class="title">
            {{ generateTitle(onlyOneChild.meta.title) }}
          </span>
        </div>
        </el-card>
    
      </app-link>
    </template>
  <!-- group -->

        <template   v-else  class="childCard" v-for="child in visibleChildren" :index="resolvePath(item.path)">
     
          <app-link :to="resolvePath(child.path)">
            <el-card  class="contentClass" :index="resolvePath(child.path)">
              <div class="contentCard">
                <div class="icon">
              <i :class="child.meta.icon" />
                </div>
              <span class="title">
                {{ generateTitle(child.meta.title) }}
              </span>
         </div>
            </el-card>
          </app-link>
        </template>
   
      </div>    

  </template>
```

Here is my css styling

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
  .el-menu--inline span{
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  
  .el-menu-item svg{
    margin-right: 11px;
  }
  
  .el-menu-item-group__title {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .is-active .menu-dot{
    background: #cca13c;
  }

  .menu-dot {
    width: 21px;
    background: #304156;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }


.contentClass{
  margin-right:20px;
}

.childCard{
  flex-grow:1;
}
.contentCard{
  display:grid;
}

.icon{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.title{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.el-card{
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 145px;
  min-width: 250px;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.menu-wrapper{

  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  min-height: fit-content;
  
}
  
  </style>
```

Thank You

Edit: since it may be confusing what i said above,  to try to be more simple,  i have several wrappers with cards inside it, in one line.   If i had one card per wrapper, my code would work properly , however, some of my wrappers have 2 or more cards inside, and when it reaches the limit of the screen (especially if is a small screen), the entire wrapper goes to the next line, instead, i only want the card that doensn't have space to fit in the same line, inside that wrapper, to change to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by doing an workaround (and i post what i did so it may help anyone who had similar problem as me), and simply ungroup my children.  I was using a routes method, that simply was  retunirng my $store.state.permission.routes, and doing all the magic on my template.     I changed my approach and did all the magic on the routes method, and then simpply passing an object array with my ungrouped components, like this:

```
      routes() {
        
this.rotas = this.$store.state.permission.routes;
console.log(this.$store.state.permission.routes)

var k=0;



  for(let i in this.rotas){

    if( !this.rotas[i].hidden&&this.rotas[i].children){

      if(this.hasOneShowingChild(this.rotas[i].children,this.rotas[i]) && (!this.onlyOneChild.children||this.onlyOneChild.noShowingChildren) && !this.rotas[i].alwaysShow){
      this.result[k]= this.rotas[i];
      this.result[k].meta=this.rotas[i].children[0].meta;
      k++;
      
    }
    else{
      var childrens =  this.rotas[i].children.filter(item => !item.hidden);

      for(let child in childrens){
        this.result[k]= childrens[child];
        k++;
      
      }
    
    }

  }
  }
  return this.result;
    },
```

and my template now

```
<template>
   <div class="menu-wrapper">

   
      <app-link :to="resolvePath(item.path)">
        <!-- single -->
        
        <el-card   :index="resolvePath(item.path)" :class="{'submenu-title-noDropdown':!isNest} ">
          <!-- <item v-if="onlyOneChild.meta" :title="onlyOneChild.meta.title" /> -->          
          <!-- <item v-if="onlyOneChild.meta" :icon="onlyOneChild.meta.icon||item.meta.icon" :title="onlyOneChild.meta.title" :collapse="collapse" /> -->
          <!-- <span>{{ onlyOneChild.meta.title }}</span> -->
          <div class="contentCard">
            <div class="icon">
          <i :class="item.meta.icon" />
        </div>
          <span class="title">
            {{ generateTitle(item.meta.title) }}
          </span>
        </div>
        </el-card>
    
      </app-link>
    
   
      </div>    

  </template>
```